# How to show that the $1+\sum_{n=1}^{m }10^n$ can not be a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I think there is only one prime number which is $11$,but the $111,1111,11111,...$ can not be prime, so I want to show that
  $$1+\sum_{n=1}^{m }10^n$$ can not be  a prime number when $m>1$ How should I approach this problem?

Comment: There are [further primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit#Decimal_repunit_primes) in the sequence.

Comment: @DanielFischer I wouldn't let that stop *me*!

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called "repunits".
Look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit

Here are the initial $n$
such that
$\frac{10^n-1}{9}
$
are prime:

2, 19, 23, 317, 1031

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel Fischer pointed out in comments above, the claim is untrue.

$\underbrace{1111111111111111111}_{19~\text{ones}}$

and

$\underbrace{11111111111111111111111}_{23~\text{ones}}$

are both prime.

See https://oeis.org/A004022 for additional terms and information.